# flutter ios build error on code magic mac m1

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, codemagic, flutter-ios-build

I am getting this weird error  about the file name that is being created when I try to build ios app with the release flag ,I have no idea where this error is originating but  I think there is something in the file :

```
ios/flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist
```

the above file was missing and I was getting an error because of that so I crated it manually by copying it from  a freshly created flutter app , and now I am getting this weird error after the build , please help:

```
Xcode build done.                                           70.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): '/Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app/Runner.app' is longer than filepath buffer size (1025).

Encountered error while building for device.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that something is nested recursion here. Navigate into the `Build phases` tab and check the `Copy Build Bundle Resource` to remove the `Runner` (if exists). After that, you need to uncheck the `target membership` of the Runner in the right site of xcode.
[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks , I removed the runner and it worked , but I didn't know how to do the second step, anyways thank you.